# How many spell scrolls can I have at my disposal?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have a bunch of scrolls handy of all different levels. My DM says I can only have access to one scroll at a time that I must choose. Does this sound correct?

Comment: What does "access" mean here?

Comment: Only one that i can get my hands on

Comment: @Szega I think may mean *Does* access *here mean in your character's actual current possession secreted somewhere about his person* **or** *recorded on the character's character sheet?* That is, is the DM saying *In the heat of combat, you can only access one scroll at a time—you'll have to spend extra time digging around for the rest* **or** is the DM saying *Your character is only allowed to cast from one scroll each day because* reazonz *and the remaining scrolls are inert, but  the PC can pick a new one each day* or something?

Comment: "My DM says I can only have access to one scroll at a time" - according to your DM, what exactly happens when you take two scrolls and put them into your backpack?

Comment: Yes, in the heat of combat, you can only access one scroll at a time—you'll have to spend extra time digging around for the rest

Comment: *Idle Curiosity:* Does the DM also say *In the heat of combat, you can only access one weapon at a time—you'll have to spend extra time digging around for the rest*? Or is this restriction placed solely on your gotta-catch-all-the-scrolls PC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For you, one

Your DM has decided the answer to this question in her game, other DMs may decide differently in different games. I can find nothing in either the rules on magic items or the rules of combat to suggest your DM's ruling is contrary to them.

Personally, I can imagine you with a bandolier of scrolls just like the rogue has a bandolier of daggers and you whipping out the one you need with practised ease. But I'm not your DM.

Answer (score 3):

### There is precedent for requiring an action to get an item

There is no specific RAW that I could find that addresses this question, so it's up to your DM to decide. Based on similar rules, it's reasonable for your DM to decide that you can only easily access one scroll at a time.

Specifically, the extraplanar storage items require you to use an action to get an item from them. Heward's Handy Haversack states (DMG 174),

> Retrieving an item from the haversack requires you to use an action. When you reach into the haversack for a specific item, the item is always magically on top.

And the Bag of Holding says (DMG 153)

> Retrieving an item from the bag requires an action.

Note that even though the item is always magically on top for the haversack, it still costs you an action to pull it out.

Finally, in the section on item interactions, the PHB gives the DM latitude for making object interactions more difficult (PHB 190):

> The DM might require you to use an action for any of these activities when it needs special care or when it presents an unusual obstacle.